# How to collect logs from EC2 instance and store it in S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

- Step 1: Created an Amazon S3 Bucket
- Step 2: Created an IAM User with Full Access to Amazon S3 and CloudWatch Logs
- Step 3: Granted Permissions on an Amazon S3 Bucket

What should I do next?

Answer (score 2):

A few things.

1. You're probably better off using an IAM instance profile. That way, your credentials are not static IAM user credentials.
2. If you want to only copy the logs to S3, I'd suggest setting up some scheduled job to use the AWS CLI to copy the directory with your logs to S3.

Alternatively, I'd suggest you install and configure the CloudWatch agent on your instance. From there, you can copy logs to S3 using the methodology outlined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasks.html